# cannot run function click with multilevel push menu in meteor

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, meteor

I am a newbie in meteor and also in jQuery.

I am trying to explore meteor with multi level push menu from http://tympanus.net/Development/MultiLevelPushMenu/ ..

The scenario is simple, so I have a navigation menu (ex: Home, About Me, etc) on the left side and a container in right side. When I click the navigation menu, I want to show a template in my container side.

Just an example if I click "Home" in my navigation menu, then the container side will display Home Template. Or, if I click "About Me" menu, then the container side will display AboutMe Template.

I want to make it with a reactive menu using meteor session.

I can't give all my code here because it's too long, so here is my essential code:

.html:

```
<template name="MainTemplate">
    <div class="container">
        <div class="mp-pusher" id="mp-pusher">
            <h2 style="margin-left: 20px"><a href="#" id="trigger" class="menu-trigger">Open/Close Menu</a></h2>
            <!-- mp-menu -->
            <nav id="mp-menu" class="mp-menu">
                <div class="mp-level">
                    <ul>
                        <li><a class="icon icon-shop" href="/MainTemplate">Home</a></li>
                        <li><a class="icon icon-search" href="#" id="ViewGrid">View in Grid</a></li>
                    </ul>
                </div>
            </nav>
            <!-- /mp-menu -->

            {{>scroller}}

        </div><!-- /pusher -->
    </div><!-- /container -->
</template>

<template name="scroller">
    <div class="scroller"><!-- this is for emulating position fixed of the nav -->
        <div class="scroller-inner">

            {{#if currentViewIs "GridHeroes"}}
                {{>GridHeroes}}
            {{else}}
                {{>logo}}
            {{/if}}

        </div><!-- /scroller-inner -->
    </div><!-- /scroller -->
</template>

<template name="logo">
    <div>
        <img src="../marveldc.jpg"/>
    </div>
</template>
```

.js :

```
Template.scroller.currentViewIs = function(view) {
        if(Session.get('currentView') == view)
            return true;
        return false;
    };

    Template.MainTemplate.events() ({
        'click #ViewGrid':function(event, template){
            alert('ab');
            Session.set('currentView', 'GridHeroes');
        }
    });
```

My problem is when I click the link on navigation menu, it cannot render a new template in container side. Even my alert can't show too.

Any idea how to make it work?

Comment: What is not working? Do you get errors? Please elaborate.

Comment: i dont get any errors. i just cannot render a new template when i click the tab menu. even i cant show the alert. what i want to achieve is when i click the tab menu on the left side, the new template will rendered on the right side. the example layout just like http://www.jonathandacosta.com/

Comment: Your question is absolute inaccurate described. The example is not complete e.g. `#ViewGrid` is nowhere in template etc. If you are interested in help you should better describe what you are looking for, what you have done and what is not working. To show more complete running examples you may use MeteorPad.com and create an example for your question.

Comment: Hi Tom, sorry to make you confused. i've editted my question, hope you can understand it now.